# read and output a text file using streamreader char by char

Tags: c#

what i am trying to do is to read the file a.txt and output each character in a single line i am having a real difficulty to solve this problem any help will be really appreciated.if you write the code please comment so i can understand more clearly as i am beginner.thanks

```
namespace ConsoleApplication13
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("a.txt"))
            {

               string @char;
               while((@char = r.ReadBlock() != null))
                foreach(char i in @char)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);

                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're purpose... is it char-by-char? or line-by-line? or...? it isn't entirely clear what you are trying to do

Comment: this is the actual code which i am sure i am not doing right :)

Comment: ok; fair enough - but can you clarify what *exactly* you are trying to do?

Comment: @MarcGravell i want to read the file and output all the file char by char , each char in new line

Comment: You can use BinaryReader instead of StreamReader. It has ReadChar() method.

Comment: thanks @monti i will check it out and ref will be helpful though

Comment: You can read about BinaryReader here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.100).aspx. Also there is a code example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> i want to read the file and output all the file char by char , each char in new line

OK; there's a lot of ways to do that; the simplest would be (for small files):

```
string body = File.ReadAllText("a.txt");
foreach (char c in body) Console.WriteLine(c);
```

To use `ReadBlock` to handle the file in chunks (not lines):

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("a.txt"))
{
    char[] buffer = new char[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = r.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < read; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(buffer[i]);
    }
}
```

This reads blocks of *up to* 1024 characters at a time, then writes out whatever we read, each character on a new line. The variable `read` tells us how many characters we read on that iteration; the `read > 0` test (hidden slightly, but it is there) asks "have we reached the end of the file?" - as `ReadBlock` will return 0 at the end.

Comment: thanks that was really helpful.so the read block only can read 1024 char before write or it can take more?

Comment: @Geek you can make the buffer any size you like; it is a compromise though, between loading everything into memory at once (an overly large buffer), and making lots of trips to the IO stack (have a too-small buffer). Typical IO buffers are between (as a very rough guide) 512 bytes to 8k (8192 bytes). 1024 was simply as "good enough for most situations, fairly cheap to allocate". Note we are using the ***same*** buffer for every iteration - so you can process a 200MB file using just a 1k buffer.

Comment: thanks marc that was extremely valuable and helpful thanks again :)