# FileStream Overflow Exception

Tags: c#, overflowexception

Get an overflow exception when trying to run an eof statement in the while loop **Value was either too large or too small for a character**

```
string filePath = @"C:\Users\Klanix\Desktop\NewC#\testfile2.txt";

        FileStream fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open);

        char readChar;
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];

        while(fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length) > 0)
        {
            readChar = Convert.ToChar(fs.ReadByte());
            Console.WriteLine(readChar);
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985348/read-and-output-a-text-file-using-streamreader-char-by-char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you read 1024 byte of the file (that may be you reach the end of file) then you try to read the next byte that in this case would return -1 and can not be converted to char.

Why would you even read that first 1024 byte? 
Try reading 1 byte each time:

```
string filePath = @"C:\Users\Klanix\Desktop\NewC#\testfile2.txt";
FileStream fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open);
int val;
while((val = fs.ReadByte()) > 0)
{
     readChar = Convert.ToChar(val);
     Console.WriteLine(readChar);
}
```

and you won't need `byte[] b = new byte[1024];`

Comment: Thank you I see the error I committed now. Thanks for clearing my benevolence :).

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `fs.ReadByte()` without first checking that `fs` still has a byte left.  Because you are calling `while(fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length) > 0)` you will most likely empty `fs` into `b`, then call `fs.ReadByte()` resulting in your error.

Try something like:

```
string filePath = @"C:\Users\Klanix\Desktop\NewC#\testfile2.txt";

FileStream fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open);

for (int i = 0; i < fs.Length; i++)
{
    char readChar = Convert.ToChar(fs.ReadByte());
    Console.WriteLine(readChar);
}
```

Try also reading the documentation for [ReadByte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.readbyte(v=vs.110).aspx).